# Mongrel2 send_spec and recv_spec

Tags: zeromq, mongrel2

I have just started messing around with Mongrel2, all the tutorials went great until I started pointing a Mongrel2 Handlers send_spec and recv_spec to an address other than localhost, for example a second machine on the network.

I started getting these errors:

```
errno: Resource temporarily unavailable) Failed to bind send socket trying again for: tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49901
```

My question is when there are two nodes A and B, where A is the Mongrel2 server and B is a "worker" for one of A's handlers, what addresses would go into the send_spec and recv_spec of A's .conf file?

I'm sorry if this is a naive question, it just has me so confused.

Answer (score 0):

The **PUSH** (`send_spec`) and **SUB** (`recv_spec`) ports on NodeA (*Mongrel2 Server*) are the binding sockets so you should use `tcp://*:<port>`.  By using the `*` for the address you can received connections from any interface.

Your handler code is where the specific address is needed.  I use docker containers to run my Python handlers so I am always needing to use the specific IP address for the container running the Mongrel2 Server `tcp://172.16.1.?:<port>`.

If all these are **true**:

- The Docker containers are allowed to talk to each other
- You are using the correct IP and PORTs
- The PUSH and SUB specs are receiving from all interfaces

Your handler should be able to connect.